# JSF navigation parameter dependency

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to implement this simple example in JSF: There is a user.xhtml page which can be accessed with an *id* parameter (user.xhtml?id=3 / user.xhtml?id=12). Depending on the id The page should display the info of the user who has that specified id.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OverviewController extends BaseController{

private UserDetails details;

@PostConstruct
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void init(){
    Integer userId = getIntegerParam(Constants.PARAMETER_USER); //this brings the value of the user parameter as an Integer
    if (userId != null){
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        details = userService .getDetails(userId);
    }
}

//GET & SET
```

}

In the xhtml file I have the followings:

```
<div>
    Name: #{overviewController.details.name}
    City: #{overviewController.details.city}
</div>
```

The link which guided the control here:

```
<h:link outcome = "user.xhtml" value = "details">
    <f:param name = "user" value = "2">
</h:link>
```

I was under the impression that when accessing the overviewController via EL the ManagedBean will get Constructed and in the @PostConstruct the *details* would get initialised. But I get no results and the overviewController isn't even constructed.
I'm going further with my question and I ask how can a search depending on multiple parameters or a sort can be implemented?

Comment: Is the `OverviewController` class annotated with `@ManagedBean(name="overviewController")` or `@Named("overviewController")`?

Comment: Also, there should probably be a scope annotation, such as `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: It is nor necessary. If the name is not declared the JSF takes the class name, transforms the first letter of the class in small caps and takes it as the name of the bean.

Comment: Ok, so where is the `getIntegerParam` method defined?

Comment: Yes. All the needed methods are defined. Furthermore I created a PhaseListener and I saw that none of the phases except the restore (1) and render(6) are invoked. That is, I believe, because <h:link> sends a GET request. But I don't know any other alternative to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your concrete problem, your `@PostConstruct` is incorrectly been declared `private` instead of `public`.

As to your concrete functional requirement, this is not entirely the right way. You need a `<f:viewParam>` in the target page to set the user ID request parameter as an `UserDetails` property in the backing bean.

`user.xhtml`

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="param_id" name="id" value="#{overviewController.details}"
        converter="userDetailsConverter" converterMessage="Bad request, unknown user"
        required="true" requiredMessage="Bad request, use a link from within the system"
    />
</f:metadata>
<h:message for="param_id" />
```

`UserDetailsConverter`

```
@FacesConverter("userDetailsConverter")
public class UserDetailsConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof UserDetails) || ((UserDetails) value).getId() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return String.valueOf(((UserDetails) value).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || !value.matches("\\d+")) {
            return null;
        }

        UserDetails details = new UserService().getDetails(Integer.valueOf(value));

        if (details == null) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Unknown user ID: " + value));
        }

        return details;
    }

}
```

`OverviewController`

```
private UserDetails details; // Getter+setter
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why doesn't the @PostConstruct from my example never gets called?

Comment: Because you declared it `private` instead of `public`.

Comment: I have one more question. I fallowed your example but I get the following warning: WARNING: JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt26. I'm guessing that I'm not using the viewParam tag correctly right?

Comment: There's somewhere in the page a `<h:link outcome>` or `<h:button outcome>` which does not have the proper `outcome` value. The respective component has the client ID `j_idt26`. Check in the generated HTML source to trackback the original culprit in the Facelet source. This is unrelated to the `<f:viewParam>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how your method `getIntegerParam` actually works, but I usually implement processing query parameters like this.

**Edit**: I'm not actually sure if the `init()` would be really invoked after the `userId` property is set (I usually invoked it directly from the setter), but it probably should as `@PostConstruct` methods are invoked after dependencies are injected.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OverviewController extends BaseController {

    @ManagedProperty("#{param['userId']}")
    private String userId; // not sure if can automatically be parsed to Integer

    private UserDetails details;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        if (userId != null){
            UserService userService = new UserService();
            details = userService .getDetails(userId);
        }
    }

    // getter & setter for userId
}
```